# SessionToken disappeared because of Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError

Tags: android, parsing, session

When I used Parse session -> enableRevocableSessionInBackground

After some event listener, I got this message. I logged into my app using parse logiinbackground api. I dont know why I got this message Please help me.

```
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
    ParseUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground();

        ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, passwd, new
                LogInCallback() {

                    public void done(ParseUser user,                com.parse.ParseException e) {
```

At this time ParseUser.isAuthenticated is true and sessiontoken is not null

But after some event          btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       -> in Here ParseUser.isAuthenticated is false and sessiontoken is null
```

}}

Thus, because at the event time session token disappeared I got the message Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError

I don't know why this phenomenon happened please help me.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?